# Flutter dialog is not displaying when button is pressed

Tags: flutter

```
child: RaisedButton(
  color: const Color(0xFF5867DD),
  onPressed: (){
     updateProfilePic();           
  },



 Widget updateProfilePic(){
    return SimpleDialog(
      title: const Text('Select any option'),
             children: <Widget>[
          SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () {  profileImg = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
                .whenComplete(() {
              setState(() {});
            }); },
            child: const Text('open gallery'),
          ),
          SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () {   profileImg = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
                .whenComplete(() {
              setState(() {});
            }); },
            child: const Text('open camera'),
          ),
        ],
    );
  }
```

I am trying to implement Dialog when the button is pressed.I want to select image from gallery and camera so that i created a dialog to select any option to upload the picture.The issue is when i click the button dialog is not visible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to call [showDialog](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(title),
          content: Text(message),

        );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Figen Güngör](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1463542/figen-g%C3%BCng%C3%B6r) You need to call [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html).
Just want to clarify that it is a Future (function) not a Widget, therefore your code would be like this:

```
    Future updateProfilePic(BuildContext context){
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder : (BuildContext context){
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: const Text('Select any option'),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {  profileImg = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
                  .whenComplete(() {
                setState(() {});
              }); },
              child: const Text('open gallery'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {   profileImg = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
                  .whenComplete(() {
                setState(() {});
              }); },
              child: const Text('open camera'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```